# synchronization between a java app and C++ app in windows

Tags: java, c++, windows, synchronization

I have two apps, one is written in java and the other one in C++ (both on windows platform).

Both these apps are trying to access a single resource and I want to put some kind of synchronization mechanism.
How do I do this?

Is there a way to access the windows kernel objects like mutex, events, semaphore in a Java code and wait for it?

What would be a standard approach to solve this kind of issue?

Thanks & Regards
Sunil

Comment: My naive solution would be to communicate with sockets over a local network. But then you don't get atomic operations.. I'm curious to see the "correct" solution

Comment: Well, for the windows-specific c++ world you can have a look at the [msdn on inter process synchronisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, I'm not sure if any of those options are easily available from Java.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to sync:

- Access IPC sync primitives from java via JNI (a.k.a. native methods) - [Oracle's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/).
- Use sockets to send/recieve signals.
- Use file as a sync object: Java 7 has brand new API for woring with file system - [WatcherService can be used to see changes on FS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).